# Finding distinct values in array column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Postgresql with ActiveRecord in Rails 4.

I have a customer model and one of the columns is called "tags" and it is an array column (["sports", "broadcasting"]).

How can I select all the distinct values from this column? I would like to avoid doing anything where I would have to instantiate AR objects due to the amount of customer records we have. So I don't want something like:

`Customer.select(:tags).map(&:tags).flatten.uniq`

which works but uses too much memory.

I need the values to provide suggestions when someone is adding a tag to a customer. Hopefully it will help prevent variations of words or misspellings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `Customer.pluck(:tags).flatten.uniq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`pluck`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) like below

```
Customer.pluck(:tags).flatten.uniq
```